# Filter table data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, datatable

I want to filter a table based on few conditions .. Below is the sample image
[image: sample]

code I've tried

```
    this.reportData.filter(it => {
        if (
            it.startTimeFilter.includes(this.startdatefilter) &&
            it.endTimeFilter.includes(this.enddatefilter) &&
            it.status.toLowerCase().includes(this.status)
        ) {
            this.filteredData.push(it);
        }
    });
```

Comment: and what do you expect as an answer ? Be more specific and tell us: `what was the output from current code and what more you want to see`

Comment: current code working  only if i choose all the fields .. But i want to filter based on individual field  ..

Comment: See user can give any comibation like status and browser or os  and startdate .. so like that how do I do filter .. I'm not getting any idea also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I can give you some hint to achieve this as I do not have full code.  Make sure `this.reportData` is never changed as we need all data to have filtering

```
 applyFiltering(){
    this.dataToShowOnUI = getFilteredData();
 }

 getFilteredData(): any[]{
    let filteredData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.reportData));
    if(this.startdatefilter && this.enddatefilter){
      filteredData = filteredData.filter(it => 
            it.startTimeFilter.includes(this.startdatefilter) &&
            it.endTimeFilter.includes(this.enddatefilter) 
      );
    }
    if(this.status){
     filteredData = filteredData.filter(data => data.status.toLowerCase().includes(this.status))
    }
    if(this.operatingSystem){
        filteredData = filteredData.filter(data => data.operatingSystem.toLowerCase().includes(this.operatingSystem))
    }
    // and so on ...
    return filteredData;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `this.reportData` and `this.filteredData` are arrays. Then the correct way of using `filter` method is the following:

```
this.filteredData = this.reportData.filter(it => 
    it.startTimeFilter.includes(this.startdatefilter) &&
    it.endTimeFilter.includes(this.enddatefilter) &&
    it.status.toLowerCase().includes(this.status)
);
```

Basically, the parameter of filter should be a function that returns boolean value (which tells if the element should be kept as result), and it returns the filtered new array without modifying the given one.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. I tried this but for me return didn't work so I'm assigning filter value to array then showing .. and reportdata is the array that i'm displaying for table.. filtereddata is just a temp variable.

Comment: And the code I've given that working fine for all the fields .. but  I want to filter based on individual filed.

Comment: In that case, say for example you don't want to assign `this.startdatefilter`, make sure that you make it an empty string `""`. Then `.includes("")` will return true and you should get what you want.